# Calculate update frequency in R data

Tags: r

I have several clients sending data to a server, on the server we have a log that tracks client id and sending time like this

```
ClientID, Time
"client_1",1548736876
"client_2",1548736800
"client_1",1548737070
"client_1",1548737249
"client_2",1548738902
...
```

I would like to calculate the average update interval for all clients

for client_1: `((1548737249-1548737070) + (1548737070 - 1548736876))/2`

for client_2: `(1548738902-1548736800)`

`avg = (client_1 + client_2)/2`

How it can be done in R?

Comment: Could you add a table showing your expected output?

Comment: @NelsonGon, the final result is just avg. time, not a table

Answer (score 0):

You can use data table like this

```
ClientID <- c("client_1", "client_2", "client_1", "client_1", "client_2")
Time <- c(1548736876, 1548736800, 1548737070, 1548737249, 1548738902)
df <- data.table(ClientID = ClientID, Time = Time)
df

   ClientID       Time
1: client_1 1548736876
2: client_2 1548736800
3: client_1 1548737070
4: client_1 1548737249
5: client_2 1548738902
```

**Calculate Difference of time per client ID**

```
diffdf <- df[, .(difftime = diff(Time)), .(ClientID)]
diffdf

   ClientID difftime
1: client_1      194
2: client_1      179
3: client_2     2102
```

**Calculate Avg of time per client ID**

```
Avgdf <- diffdf[,.(Avg = mean(difftime)), .(ClientID)]
Avgdf

   ClientID    Avg
1: client_1  186.5
2: client_2 2102.0
```

**Calculate Final Avg**

```
TotalAvg = mean(Avgdf$Avg)
TotalAvg
1144.25
```

Comment: @vinh can you please accept my answer if it solved your problem